# Failed to connect to CRM: BadConnect Error Message received when using Azure DevOps to deploy Dynamics 365 Solution

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, dynamics-crm

I've created a Release Pipeline to pick up an artifact (solution_managed.zip) and then use Powershell to import it into the Destination Dynamics 365 instance. However, it fails at the powershell step with the following error message.

```
2020-06-02T14:51:12.5841072Z ##[section]Starting: Import Managed To CRM Instance
2020-06-02T14:51:12.6002600Z ==============================================================================
2020-06-02T14:51:12.6002938Z Task         : PowerShell
2020-06-02T14:51:12.6004008Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
2020-06-02T14:51:12.6004287Z Version      : 2.169.0
2020-06-02T14:51:12.6005775Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-06-02T14:51:12.6006161Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
2020-06-02T14:51:12.6006533Z ==============================================================================
2020-06-02T14:51:13.9155388Z Generating script.
2020-06-02T14:51:13.9699366Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2020-06-02T14:51:14.0002575Z ##[command]"C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\d3714af1-e235-4350-94a4-38f071d5ef84.ps1'"
2020-06-02T14:51:20.2572221Z WARNING: Failed to connect to CRM: BadConnect
2020-06-02T14:51:20.2636417Z WARNING: Failed to connect to CRM: Exception while trying to connect Discovery Server, (Global Discovery) URI is = 
2020-06-02T14:51:20.2641307Z https://globaldisco.crm.dynamics.com/api/discovery/v2.0/InstancesNo Orgs Found, Searched Online. Region Setting = UK
2020-06-02T14:51:20.5879794Z Get-CrmConnection : Failed to connect to CRM: Exception while trying to connect Discovery Server, (Global Discovery) 
2020-06-02T14:51:20.5881239Z URI is = https://globaldisco.crm.dynamics.com/api/discovery/v2.0/InstancesNo Orgs Found, Searched Online. Region 
2020-06-02T14:51:20.5881988Z Setting = UK
2020-06-02T14:51:20.5882879Z At D:\a\_temp\d3714af1-e235-4350-94a4-38f071d5ef84.ps1:7 char:9
2020-06-02T14:51:20.5883876Z + $conn = Get-CrmConnection -Credential $cred -DeploymentRegion UK -OnL ...
2020-06-02T14:51:20.5884666Z +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-06-02T14:51:20.5885741Z     + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Get-CrmConnection], Exception
2020-06-02T14:51:20.5886805Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : -3,Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnector.Powershell.Commands.GetCrmConnectionCommand
2020-06-02T14:51:20.5887564Z  
2020-06-02T14:51:20.7768883Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2020-06-02T14:51:20.8487239Z ##[section]Finishing: Import Managed To CRM Instance
```

Here is my Powershell script (or Powershell Task in Azure DevOps)

```
$user = "****@*****.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "********"
$SecPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user, $SecPassword)
$conn = Get-CrmConnection -Credential $cred -DeploymentRegion UK -OnLineType Office365 -OrganizationName orgc35b4e33
Import-CrmSolution -conn $conn -SolutionFilePath $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/*****/drop/PhoneBook_managed.zip
```

However, the same PS script works when I run it on my local machine. Any ideas on why this works on my local machine (and deploys the managed solution to the destination crm instance) and yet this same script throws this error when I try and run it in an AzureDevOps step?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: why would you reinvent the wheel ? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WaelHamze.xrm-ci-framework-build-tasks

Comment: I work for a company where third party tools are not preferred due to the security environment we work in.